# SAS PROC SQL - How to add months to a date

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How can I add months to a date?
I've tried the function `ADD_MONTHS(<my date>, 6)` and `DATEADD(Month, 6, <my date>)` but both functions are not recognized.

What's the correct function to use?

Comment: sounds like **INTNX** issue. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_tsdata_sect038.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in [sas community](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/What-do-you-guys-use-in-place-of-DateADD-in-a-Proc-SQL/td-p/132172): function intnx()

```
proc sql;
    select *,intnx('month',<my_date>, 6) as incdate format=date9. from have;
quit;
```